# Java Servlet: Add delay without asynchronous processing?

Tags: java, servlets

We are running a Spring MVC / Security 3.x web application with a protected area behind a login. In order to improve our security, we would like to add an increasing delay each time a malicous user or bot retries failing logins (against brute-forcing), like [described by Jeff](https://blog.codinghorror.com/dictionary-attacks-101/) below the headline "Limiting the number.." or [at OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Blocking_Brute_Force_Attacks).

Our application runs in Tomcat 7 with [Servlet Spec v2.5](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-2.5-mrel2-eval-oth-JSpec/) which means we do not have asynchronous servlets, and `Thread.sleep()` is a no-go anyway, because this would block the executing thread (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037524/tomcat-chokes-after-6-requests)) and quickly exhaust the thread pool for processing, effectively resulting in a DoS attack against our server. [Others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526614/sleep-in-java-web-application/17526836#17526836) have been pointing this out already, so my question is:

- How can I add an arbitrary delay to servlet processing without resorting to multithreading on the server side?

I would like to avoid setting up a custom thread pool for processing, since the servlet spec also states that passing the request / response objects to other threads is not thread-safe (chapter 2.3.3.3 in the Servlet spec linked above).

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to add this into code. You can probably do it easier on the reverse proxy level.

Comment: @Kayaman Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately I do not have control over the infrastructure but will raise this as a question with our hoster.

Comment: You can do the _opposite_ - store a `Map<Something, Delayer>`, where `Something` you will have decide yourself; IP should be sufficient for most uses. Then, when a user tries to log in, if they are not present in the `Map` and fail to log in, enter them into the `Map` and set the number of failed attempts to `1`. Now, when they exceed a certain number of failed attempts in a time window, then fail all their logins until that window expries. This way, your server doesn't wait but you do prevent brute force.

Comment: This is definitely something that should be configured on the proxy side. They're meant for that and already have [the tools](https://www.knthost.com/nginx/brute-force-protection-nginx-proxy).

Comment: @Kayaman Thanks for the link, very useful!